# How to fit SVG into parent object in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

How do i set the SVG size in the Fabric.js `loadSVGFromString` method?
I've could not find any solution to fit into a parent object (`groupSVGElements`). Also checked the docs, but everywhere i just saw they use always that canvas size which size has the SVG.

Example: http://codepen.io/bajzarpa/pen/wJOOdB?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, your current SVG Element does not contain any *width* and *height* property, you'll need to use `viewBox.baseVal.width` and `viewBox.baseVal.height` to get it's *width* and *height* respectively and set it accordingly to fit into a parent object.

```
// get the svg's width and height
let svg = document.querySelector('#testvg');
let svgWidth = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
let svgHeight = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height;

// set to fit into a parent object (canvas)
graphic.set({
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    width: svgWidth,
    height: svgHeight,
    scaleX: (canvas.width - 10) / svgWidth,
    scaleY: (canvas.height - 10) / svgHeight
 });
```

[**WORKING DEMO on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZgopR?editors=0010)

Comment: What i want is the opposite of your solution. I want to shrink the SVG file into a fixed size canvas. Sorry if the original question was not clear.